# Getting HTTP 404 when trying to access Swagger UI and API-specification YAML file

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc

According to https://springdoc.org/v2 it should be enought to add `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` to my dependencies in order to get the Swagger UI running.

Also, under http://localhost:8081/v3/api-docs.yaml I whould find the YAML description of the API.

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<!-- ... -->

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

<dependencies>
```

However, if I am accessing http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html or http://localhost:8081/v3/api-docs.yaml what I get is an HTTP 404 error.

For tesing purposes, I have completely disabled the `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(
            (config) -> {
                try {
                    config.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")).permitAll();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
    );

    return http.build();
}
```

#### Log-Output

```
2023-03-28T21:11:59.113+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@6f50e1f9
2023-03-28T21:11:59.113+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@62698810
2023-03-28T21:11:59.113+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-03-28T21:11:59.113+02:00  INFO 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-03-28T21:11:59.114+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /v3/api-docs.yaml
2023-03-28T21:11:59.114+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /v3/api-docs.yaml
2023-03-28T21:11:59.114+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/v3/api-docs.yaml", parameters={}
2023-03-28T21:11:59.115+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2023-03-28T21:11:59.117+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2023-03-28T21:11:59.117+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-03-28T21:11:59.117+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-03-28T21:11:59.118+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-03-28T21:11:59.118+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2023-03-28T21:11:59.118+02:00 DEBUG 47546 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
```

Comment: Did you actually call http://server:port/context-path/swagger-ui.html? "context-path" is just a placeholder for, well, the context path. In most plain spring boot applications this is simply empty, so http://server:port/swagger-ui.html should be fine.

Comment: @schrom I think I tried all the variations there are ^^ nothing seems to work and I can't see the problem. Here's a fun fact: I have a script which runs `mvn clean install -P openapi` and as such the server in order to generate an OpenAPI TypeScript client for me. That works without issues. But if I want to render the UI on my local development server.. I get the HTTP 404 ...

Comment: I did a small project and it's working out of the box. https://github.com/schrom/springdoc-test (kotlin if you don't mind). Just clone it and start it in IntelliJ oder mvnw spring-boot:run, you can acces springdoc on 'http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html'.

Answer (score 0):

Like @schrom, I found that this worked out of the box for me. The following is minimal source that works as is. application.properties is empty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbootswagger</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springbootswagger</name>
    <description>To diagnose SwaggerUi issues</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Springboot3SwaggeredApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Springboot3SwaggeredApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Springboot3SwaggeredApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

OnlyController.java

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class OnlyController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```